# .htacces RewriteEngine does not work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i thought that you guys could help me, i got this .htacces file some time back together and it worked but now i cant seem to get it working.
It worked like this:

localhost/dasds.gif --> localhost/index.php?q=dasds.gif
localhost/asd.bla --> localhost/index.php?q=asd.bla

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/?\ ]
RewriteRule .*\.php$ -[L,R=404]
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: wow so much wrong....

Comment: "can't seem to get it working". - [Explain *how* it's not working](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147616/what-do-you-mean-it-doesnt-work). Error/access.log/rewritelog and some examples, or make a screencast or something.

Comment: Provide more information about what you want to achieve, describe the problem and ask a specific question.

Comment: What URL is not working?

Answer (score 1):

Ok let me ( try to ) read this off to you

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/?\ ]
RewriteRule .*\.php$ -[L,R=404]
```

Line 2 
rewrite ^(starts with) (.*) capture anything ( including nothing ) make it index.php

Line 3 
condition continue if the request  ^(starts with) [A-Z]+ (more then 1 uppercase letter) a \ (backslash )a ' ' (space) a  / (forward slash), [^?\ ]* (not) a ? or backslash (\) or ' '(space) (]*) 0 or  more times, .php followed by [/?\ ] a forward slash a ? or a back slash one time.

Line 4
rewrite .* match anything ( including nothing ) that $ (ends with) `.php` make it - redirect to 404 error

This might not be 100% right but should be fairly close.

you could do something like this ( cant test it though )

```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
  RewriteRule ([^/]+) index.php?q=$1  [L]
```

If a real file, send to index.php ( capture name ) put in query string q

Mod rewrite can be real pain to work with.  Here is a great post on the basics https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners